# Is there way to get Skydrive access token by javascript?

Tags: javascript, access-token, onedrive

I have refresh token getted from SkyDrive. Can I get access token from SkyDrive by javascript in browser?

I tried to use XmlHttpRequest or form and iframe, but in both cases I have no access to returned data, as data is returned from other domain